# Changing a string to a date

Tags: excel

Is it possible to change a number to date using excel functions? For example:

```
1978    1
1978    2
1978    3
1978    4
1978    5
1978    6
1978    7
1978    8
1978    9
1978    10
1978    11
1978    12
```

where the right column is the month. I want to convert it to Jan1978;

Comment: have you tried any Date forumals that are built in, in ms excel ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

Simply use Date() function to get the output as a date. I assume the day to be 1st of every month.

Range C2= "=DATE(A2,B2,1)"   //Here, A2 is the year, B2 is the month and 1 is the day.

See the picture below for reference:

[image]

You can format the date as desired using TEXT function:

Range C2= **<kbd>=TEXT(DATE(A2,B2,1),"mmm-yyyy")</kbd>**

Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date() function as mentioned by Sunny. If you want only format like 'Jan1978', Right Click -> Format cells -> Choose custom number format like this:

[image]